# Serverless Framework - Setting up resource permissions for dynamodb

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I've the following **serverless.yml** file. 
I'm trying to assign read write permissions to the generated dynamodb..

So far it generates my lambda and the dynamodb table but the lambda isn't assigned permissions to access it.

I get no errors and it doesn't seem to add the permission to the dynamodb table.

Can anyone shed any light please?

```
service:
  name: catcam

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  tableName: ${self:custom.stage}-notes

environment:
  tableName: ${self:custom.tableName}

plugins:
  - '@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript'
  - serverless-plugin-optimize
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource:
        - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["NotesTable", "Arn" ] }
          #        - { !GetAtt NotesTable.Arn }

functions:
  main: # The name of the lambda function
    # The module 'handler' is exported in the file 'src/lambda'
    handler: src/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /{any+}


resources:
  Resources:
    NotesTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.tableName}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: noteId
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: noteId
            KeyType: RANGE
        # Set the capacity to auto-scale
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong with the above, **it's correct!!**.. it's was me being a banana and not matching the full name of the table with the environment in the application.. i.e. **notes** table becomes **dev-notes** for instance.. maybe the above will help someone.